# detect if modal is currently active

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, modalpopupextender

how can i detect if a modalpopupextender is currently being shown using javascript?

**Modalpopupextender markup**

```
  <!-- Add Files Modal Form -->
    <asp:HiddenField ID="AddFilesForModal" runat="server" />
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="AddFilesModal" BehaviorID="modalPopupExtenderAddFiles"
        TargetControlID="dummyButtonAddToPendingList" PopupDragHandleControlID="PanelAddFilesOuter" PopupControlID="PanelAddFilesOuter"
        OkControlID="dummyButtonAddToPendingList" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="false"
        Drag="true">
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
    <ajaxToolkit:RoundedCornersExtender ID="RoundedCornersExtender4" runat="server" TargetControlID="PanelAddFilesInner">
    </ajaxToolkit:RoundedCornersExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="PanelAddFilesOuter" runat="server"   BackColor="Transparent" Style="display: none;">
        <asp:Panel ID="PanelAddFilesInner" runat="server" BackColor="White" Style=" width:800px; height:600px;  overflow:auto;">
         <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="AddFilesContainer" style="  padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                <br />
                Add Files
                <div  id="AddFiles_Div" style="height:80%;overflow:auto;">
                            <asp:TreeView ID="TreeViewAddItems" runat="server" Height="500px"  ShowCheckBoxes="Leaf"
                                Width="380px" ImageSet="XPFileExplorer" NodeIndent="15" PathSeparator="\" ShowExpandCollapse="true"
                                EnableClientScript="true" OnTreeNodeCheckChanged="OnTreeNodeCheckChanged" OnAdaptedTreeNodeCheckChanged="OnTreeNodeCheckChanged" ShowLines="True">
                                <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#6666AA" />
                                <NodeStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="2px"
                                    NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                                <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
                                <SelectedNodeStyle BackColor="#B5B5B5" Font-Underline="False" HorizontalPadding="0px"
                                    VerticalPadding="0px" />
                            </asp:TreeView>
                            </div>
                <br />
                <div class="base" style="height:20px;">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAddToPendingList" runat="server" OnClick="BtnAddToPendingList_Click" BorderStyle="Solid" BackColor="#CCCCCC">Add selected items to list</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:Button CssClass="Button" ID="dummyButtonAddToPendingList" runat="server" Style="display: none;" />
                <asp:Button CssClass="Button" ID="CancelAddFiles" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClientClick="$find('modalPopupExtenderAddFiles').hide(); return false;" />
                </div>
                </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>
    <!-- End Add Files Modal Form -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a property you can call. You probably need to hook into the shown and hiding events. Something like this:

```
var amIVisible = false;
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function () {
    $find('modalPopupExtenderAddFiles').add_shown(function () {
        amIVisible = true;
    });

    $find('modalPopupExtenderAddFiles').add_hidden(function () {
        amIVisible = false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the BehaviourID to verify it on the client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function IsVisible()
{
    var modalPopup = $find('ModalBehaviourID');
    return modalPopup ? true : false;
}
</script>
```

Second option:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

function IsVisible()
{
    return $find('ModalBehaviourID').get_PopupVisible();
}

</script>
```

Source: [Link](http://forums.asp.net/p/1128862/1788033.aspx)

Comment: hi, i tried this and it doesnt work - the function always returns true

Comment: I think it depends on the version of the AjaxToolKit assembly. Try the other option i put on my post.

Comment: it doesn't appear to work but i didn't invest too much time on it to be fair as the solution above is working fine. thanks for the help though.